# Resharper C++ enforce C99

Tags: c, visual-studio, c99, resharper-c++

I am writing an embedded application in plain `C99` in Visual Studio with VisualGDB and Resharper c++.
The Resharper website states that it fully supports `C99`.

But if I have a typedef struct like this

```
typedef struct { int Bar;} Foo_t;
```

And some function that return this struct

```
Foo_t Foo(void){
   return (Foo_t){.Bar = 0;};
}
```

Resharper is completely confused (unreachable code, missing semicolon etc.). Is there any way to turn on `C99` standard in resharper or does it just not support this type of returns?

Comment: Resharper C++ seems to be for C++, not C...

Comment: Of course but "The Resharper website states that it fully supports C99."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are sorry for the inconvenience.
I've created an issue in YouTrack about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-15938
You can follow this request and vote for it.